# Error when deleting items from recyclerview and database

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am trying to delete item from database and recyclerview by swiping on, but when i swap last item, it doesn't deleting.
But when recyclerview doesn't have any items, when creating and then swiping on i have :
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
error.
I'm just ended android kotlin basics course and trying to create simple Note app
Here is my fragment:

```
class NoteListFragment : Fragment() {

    private val viewModel: NoteViewModel by activityViewModels {
        NoteViewModelFactory(
            (activity?.application as BaseApplication).database.noteDao()
        )
    }

    private var _binding: FragmentNoteListBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = FragmentNoteListBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val adapter = NoteListAdapter { note ->
            val action = NoteListFragmentDirections
                .actionNoteListFragmentToNoteDetailFragment(note.id)
            findNavController().navigate(action)
        }
        viewModel.allNotes.observe(this.viewLifecycleOwner) {
                note -> note.let {
            adapter.submitList(it)
            }
            ItemTouchHelper(ItemSwipe { viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder ->
                val position = viewHolder.adapterPosition
                viewModel.deleteNote(note[position])
            }).attachToRecyclerView(binding.recyclerView)
        }
        binding.apply {
            recyclerView.adapter = adapter
            addNoteFab.setOnClickListener {
                findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_noteListFragment_to_noteDetailFragment)
            }
        }

    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }

}
```

here is my adapter

```
class NoteListAdapter(
    private val clickListener: (Note) -> Unit) : ListAdapter<Note, NoteListAdapter.NoteViewHolder>(
    DiffCallBack
) {

    class NoteViewHolder(
        private var binding: ListItemNoteBinding
    ) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(note: Note) {
            binding.note = note
            binding.executePendingBindings()
        }
    }
    companion object DiffCallBack: DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Note>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Note, newItem: Note): Boolean {
            return oldItem.id == newItem.id
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Note, newItem: Note): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }

    }



    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): NoteViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        return NoteViewHolder(
            ListItemNoteBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NoteViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val note = getItem(position)
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            clickListener(note)
        }
        holder.bind(note)
    }
}
```

Comment: when creating and then swiping on i have : java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 error, from this line it seems that when you actually created any new note, it didn't get created and didn't reflect in your database and it returned an empty array. So put logs and check the issue.

Comment: @Bhavnik when i add logs to create and delete function, create function going well, and note appear on list fragment. But when trying log to delete, see this error. When after creating note i restart app, on go on another fragment and back, all works like expecting. Maybe problem in refreshing adapter list, but i don't know how to solve it.

Maybe I trying to implement that functional in wrong place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first set the adapter than change it with submitList. So change order of that:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val adapter = NoteListAdapter { note ->
            val action = NoteListFragmentDirections
                .actionNoteListFragmentToNoteDetailFragment(note.id)
            findNavController().navigate(action)
        }
        binding.apply {
            recyclerView.adapter = adapter
            addNoteFab.setOnClickListener {
                findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_noteListFragment_to_noteDetailFragment)
            }
        }
        viewModel.allNotes.observe(this.viewLifecycleOwner) {
                note -> note.let {
            adapter.submitList(it)
            }
            ItemTouchHelper(ItemSwipe { viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder ->
                val position = viewHolder.adapterPosition
                viewModel.deleteNote(note[position])
            }).attachToRecyclerView(binding.recyclerView)
        }

    }
```